# Intersection and Union between two binary tensors in theano

Tags: python, theano, lasagne

I have two binary theano tensors (prediction and target) and I want to compute the intersection and union between these two tensors, leading to Jaccard similarity coefficient.

Is there any function available in theano to do so?